# How do you pass data from FragmentA to hostActivity then update fragmentB

Tags: java, android, android-activity, bundle, fragment

I have three fragments, Player1Tun, Player2Turn and TicTacToeLayout. Player1Turn and Player2Turn are inner-switching every time a player makes a move and TicTacToeLayout contains the tic tac toe table which update everytime the fragments switches. What I'm trying to do is to send the data from either player fragments to the host activity (while the program is still running) and then from there, I'll update the table in the TicTacToeLayout. Any ideas or method I can do it?

Player1:

```
package As2.packageTK;

//import android.app.Activity;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PlayerTurn2 extends Fragment{

    TextView p2Name;
    TextView p2Icon;
    Button doneP2;
    Button resetP2;
    EditText row;
    EditText column;

    TicTacToeLayout myObject2 = new TicTacToeLayout();
    ArrayList<String> player2;
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();

    int turn = 2;



    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
    ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playerturn2, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        extras = getArguments();

        player2 = new ArrayList<String>(extras.getStringArrayList("player2"));

        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), player2.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), player2.get(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        p2Name = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.p2NameInfo);
        p2Icon = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.p2IconInfo);
        row = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rowP2);
        column = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.columnP2);
        doneP2 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.doneP2);
        //resetP2 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.resetP2);

        setPlayer(); //sets all the information of player 2, name, icon, image, etc


        doneP2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
            public void onClick(View v) {   

                callPlayer1Fragment(); //switches with first player
            }
        });
    }


    public void callPlayer1Fragment()
    {
        FragmentManager fm       = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        Fragment Player1Frag = new PlayerTurn1();
        Player1Frag.setArguments(extras);
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, Player1Frag);
        ft.commit();
    }

    public boolean checkField()
    {
        if(row == null || column == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please input the row or column!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }

        else
            return true;
    }

    public void setPlayer()
    {
        String name = player2.get(0);
        if(!name.equals(""))
            p2Name.setText("Player Name: " + name);
        else 
            p2Name.setText("");

        String icon = player2.get(1);

        if(!icon.equals(""))
            p2Icon.setText("Player Icon: " + icon);
        else
            p2Icon.setText("");
    }
}
```

player 2 fragment is exactly the same code so I won't bother adding it.

TicTacToeLayout fragment class:

```
public class TicTacToeLayout extends Fragment {

    TextView image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9;
    TextView[][] images;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
    ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tictactoe_layout, container, false);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        image1 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Image1);
        image2 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Image2);
        image3 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Image3);
        image4 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Image4);
        image5 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Image5);
        image6 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Image6);
        image7 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Image7);
        image8 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Image8);
        image9 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Image9);

        images = new TextView[][]{ {image1, image2, image3},
                                   {image4, image5, image6},
                                   {image7, image8, image9} };

        toast();
    }

    public void toast()
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), images[0][0].getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), images[0][1].getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), images[0][2].getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), images[1][0].getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void play(int row, int column, String icon)
    {
            images[row-1][column-1].setText(icon);
    }

}
```

here's the XML layout for playerturn2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tablerow0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/player2Num"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Player 2"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tablerow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/p2NameInfo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Player Name: "
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tablerow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/p2IconInfo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Player icon: "
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tablerow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/p2PicInfo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Player picture:"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

        </TableRow>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/editbox_background" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/rowNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Row (1-3):"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/rowP2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:width="50dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/colNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Col (1-3):"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/columnP2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:width="50dp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/doneP2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Done"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/resetP2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Reset"
                />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

here's the layout for tictactoelayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tictactoe"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Image1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="70dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Image2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="2"
                android:textSize="70dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Image3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="3"
                android:textSize="70dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Image4"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="4"
                android:textSize="70dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Image5"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="5"
                android:textSize="70dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Image6"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="6"
                android:textSize="70dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Image7"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="7"
                android:textSize="70dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Image8"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="8"
                android:textSize="70dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Image9"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="9"
                android:textSize="70dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/win"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Winner"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/winner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:ems="10" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </TableLayout>
```

and finally the host activity's xml layout: tictactoegame.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
         android:layout_width="0px"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" 
         android:layout_weight="1" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frag2"
            android:name="As2.packageTK.TicTacToeLayout"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

My friend did the same but with a implementing an interface he created in the fragments and having the main activity implement the interface. With that, he used a method to pass datas. Maybe it's not clear but if you know what I'm trying to say then you could clear it out for all of us :)

Answer (score 0):

your friend is right, communicating with other fragments is nicely explained in the docs:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html